# Json Formatting into plane format

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have my data as in json nested object but want to be formatted into simple json array format with the help of any javascript function. I tried doing it by for-loop but failed.

```
 var dataModel: [   {
                "phaseName" : "Closure",
                "milestone" : [ 
                    {
                        "milestoneName" : "Mile-1",
                        "startDate" : ISODate("2017-08-06T18:30:00.000Z"),
                        "endDate" : ISODate("2017-07-06T18:30:00.000Z"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("595a38e1ceb1973980406b7f")
                    }, 
                    {
                        "milestoneName" : "Mile-2",
                        "startDate" : ISODate("2017-07-04T18:30:00.000Z"),
                        "endDate" : ISODate("2017-07-13T18:30:00.000Z"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("595a4394c7a5bb3120126721")
                    }
                ]
            }
]
```

But i want my result should be formated by applying any function that convert the dataModel as

```
newModel = [{
         "phaseName":"Closure",
          "MilestoneName":"Mile-1",
          "startDate":"07/07/2017",
          "endDate":"07/15/2017"
},
{
         "phaseName":"Closure",
          "MilestoneName":"Mile-2",
          "startDate":"07/07/2017",
          "endDate":"07/15/2017"
}


]
```

Comment: you can use www.jsoneditoronline.org to reform your json

Comment: This is a very vague question. Where should you have that output? An HTML-table? A windows app? An iOS app? What languages are you using, and what have you tried?

See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What do you really need?

Comment: I have amended the question...i hope now it will be easy to understand

Comment: I want to put into angular table...so that phases and milestoneName should me in a same row

Answer (score 2):

Well if it is just for debugging, you could use [console.table](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2013/11/13/advanced-javascript-debugging-with-consoletable)

Comment: Great suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

```
var newModel = [];
for(var i = 0; i < dataModel.length; i++){
for(var e = 0; e < dataModel[i].milestone.length;e++){
  newModel.push({
    "phase": dataModel[i].phaseName,
    "milestone":dataModel[i].milestone[e].milestoneName,
   "startDate":dataModel[i].milestone[e].startDate, 
 "endDate":dataModel[i].milestone[e].endDate, 
  })

console.log(newModel)
```